# How to get the content of /dev/logo in shell?

Tags: android, linux, shell

I can read the content of /dev/logo in C,

```
fd = open("/dev/logo", O_RDONLY);

len = read(fd, logo_addr, 512);
```

Now I want to do these things using shell command, how to do?

Can I use

```
$ adb shell cat dev/logo >logo.dev
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to use `dd`? Something like:

```
dd /dev/logo bs=1 count=512 of=logo.dev
```

Assuming you need to read 512 bytes of the device.